# How to use Calendar Chart in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, charts, google-visualization

I have created couple of charts using Angular chart and now I need to add one calendar chart in the same page.I have searched calendar chart with angular but i couldn't able to find out any angular calendar chart.Then i have created calendar chart with normal google chart but I am getting some conflicts between Angular-google-chart and google chart 
Conflicts error given below

```
loader.js:148 Uncaught Error: Google Charts loader.js can only be loaded once
```

How can i solve this issue or how can i create calendar chart using Angular chart

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: need to load the `'calendar'` package for `google.visualization.Calendar` -- what are you using to load _Angular chart_?

Comment: @WhiteHat for angular chart i am using 'ng-google-chart.js'

Comment: I'm thinking it only loads `'corechart'` -- maybe try building something similar to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/i_heart_php/zh1g5305/) instead -- then you could load any package